# How do I default an application.yml value to just whitespace?

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

My `application.yml` has a value like such:

```
...
my-value: ${SOME_ENV_VAR:"   "}
...
```

I would like it to default to three space characters if `SOME_ENV_VAR` isn't present.
Unfortunately, when I read this into a String with `@ConfigurationProperties`, the quotes are included.  If I remove the quotes, I have malformed yaml and can't start up my application.  Is there any way I can get the default to simply be 3 space characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
my-value: "${SOME_ENV_VAR:\ \ \ }"
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately.